# CSS селектор для element.style.display = 'none'

Tags: javascript, css

```
let div = document.createElement("div");
div.style.display = "none";
body.appendChild(div);

let fetchedDiv = body.querySelector('div[display=none]'); // не находит
```

Как правильно написать селектор?

Comment: Воспользуйтесь [данной](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15924751/check-if-a-element-is-displaynone-or-block-on-click-jquery) ссылкой.

Comment: @Dmitry Спасибо, но я пока в jquery не лезу, можно на чистом javascript пожалуйста?

Comment: Можно, но почему не упростить себе жизнь, и не воспользоваться тем, что уже отлично работает? =)

Comment: @Dmitry Я просто изучаю javascript, пишу небольшой проект на чистом JS, хочу его закончить чтобы закрепить как следует свои знания и потом браться за изучение других языков/фреймворков и.т.д.

Comment: Я вас понял. Чтож, тогда я попытаюсь Вам помочь, ожидайте ответа.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let div = document.createElement("div");
div.style.display = "none";

// не просто body, а  document.body

document.body.appendChild(div);

let fetchedDiv = document.body.querySelector('div[style="display: none;"]');
console.log(fetchedDiv);
```